# How can I reload all my browsers at once on linux?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, reload

I'm a web designer and of course I have to work with every major browser (sans IE 6 because it is such a pain in the butt and I *need* png transparency without any workarounds).  I've been looking for a way to run and reload Firefox, a Webkit browser (Chrome), and IE 7 & 8 all at once.

(I've got the answer for my needs that I'll post below for other's reference, but I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

Browsers open:

- Google Chrome
- Firefox
- VirtualBox w/ Win XP running:

  - IE 7
  - IE 8

In my website's code I have a static title so that I can reference each browser window through its name. For example a title of "This is my title for all pages" leads to a firefox window name of "This is my title for all pages - Mozilla Firefox".

Under compiz I setup a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+j because it's easy to reach) that ran a script in /home/username/bin called refresh_all (don't forget to make this executable).

Here's the contents of refresh_all

```
#!/bin/bash

currentwindow=`xdotool getwindowfocus`

id=`xdotool search --title '[Site Title] - Google Chrome'`
xdotool windowmap $id
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    xdotool windowactivate $id
    xdotool key 'ctrl+r' $id
fi

id=`xdotool search --title '[Site Title] - Moz'`
xdotool windowmap $id
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    xdotool windowactivate $id
    xdotool key 'ctrl+r' $id
fi

id=`xdotool search --title '[Name of Virtual Machine]'`
xdotool windowmap $id
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    xdotool windowactivate $id
    xdotool key 'ctrl+r' $id
    xdotool key 'alt+Tab' $id
    xdotool key 'ctrl+r' $id
fi

#xdotool windowmap $currentwindow
xdotool windowactivate $currentwindow
```

The script works like this for me:

1. Saves the current window
2. If chrome is open, bring it to focus and simulate a Ctrl-r to reload
3. ... do the same for firefox ...
4. If the VM is open, bring it to focus to allow Win XP to catch keyboard events and simulate a Ctrl-r, then an Alt-Tab to switch to another IE version (because both IEs are running in the same VM via Utilu IE Collection) and a final Ctrl-r to refresh that one as well

You have to have xdotool (sudo apt-get install xdotool).
Uncommenting the 2nd to last line will make sure that the last window you had open will be back on top after all of the refreshing is done.

Another solution I can think of is to have an AJAX call that checks to see if a session variable called do_refresh has been set every second and if it has, refresh the browser and then writing a script that appends '|do_refresh' onto the end of all the php session files when you want to reload, but that doesn't raise the browser to the foreground (which is what I wanted because I have 4 monitors so having code on the first, chrome on the second, ie 8 & 9 on the third and firefox on the fourth and having them all come up when I make a change to my code is really nice, but if you're running with 1 or 2 monitors you may not actually want the windows to come into focus). (side note: 4 monitors isn't even enough :X If you're going to get a lot of monitors, get 6.)

Phew, that was quite the post.  Just wanted to get this info on stackoverflow so everyone can enjoy simultaneous reload ecstasy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can externally "instruct" a browser to refresh a certain tab (or at least it would be **very** complicated to support each browser). What you can do, is make the page auto-refresh every X seconds, so that you'll always have the latest version shown. Either something like:

```
<script>
  setTimeout('window.location.reload(true);', XXXXX);
</script>
```

(where XXXXX as milliseconds), or

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="Y" />
```

(where Y are seconds).